# customizing label positions in a pie chart using `ggplot2`

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart

## problem

I am trying to create a general function to draw **labelled** pie charts using `ggplot2`. What I have written works under *most circumstances*. The context in which it performs suboptimally is when there are small proportions (see the plot below). So I want to customize the positions of the label along the radial axis in such a way that they minimize overlap. Note that I can just hardcode position values for labels in such a way that it will work for *this* plot, but I would like to choose a strategy that is more generalizable.

## data

```r
# setup
set.seed(123)
library(ggplot2)

# for reproducibility
df <-
  structure(list(
    epoch = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L),
      .Label = c("Before", "After"),
      class = "factor"
    ),
    mode = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L),
      .Label = c("A", "P", "C", "T"), class = "factor"
    ),
    counts = c(30916L, 21117L, 7676L, 1962L, 1663L, 462L, 7221L,
               197L),
    perc = c(
      65.1192181312663,
      88.9586317297161,
      16.1681691802174,
      8.26522874715646,
      3.50282247872609,
      1.94624652455978,
      15.2097902097902,
      0.829892998567697
    ),
    label = c("65%", "89%", "16%", "8%",
              "4%", "2%", "15%", "1%")
  ),
  row.names = c(NA, -8L),
  class = c("tbl_df",
            "tbl", "data.frame")
  )
```

## plot

Note here that, for `After` facet, the labels are overlapping and I would like to find a general solution as to how to perturb radial positions of labels so that they overlap minimally.

How can this be done?

```r
ggplot2::ggplot(data = df, mapping = ggplot2::aes(x = "", y = perc)) +
  ggplot2::geom_col(
    mapping = ggplot2::aes(fill = mode),
    position = "fill",
    color = "black",
    width = 1,
    na.rm = TRUE
  ) + # adding label with percentages and/or counts
  rlang::exec(
    .fn = ggplot2::geom_label,
    mapping = ggplot2::aes(label = label, group = mode),
    position = ggplot2::position_fill(vjust = 0.5),
    show.legend = FALSE,
    na.rm = TRUE
  ) +
  ggplot2::facet_wrap(facets = ~epoch) +
  ggplot2::coord_polar(theta = "y")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try `geom_label_repel` from the `ggrepel` package. Just ensure you set the direction parameter to "y":

```r
ggplot2::ggplot(data = df, mapping = ggplot2::aes(x = "", y = perc)) +
  ggplot2::geom_col(
    mapping = ggplot2::aes(fill = mode),
    position = "fill",
    color = "black",
    width = 1,
    na.rm = TRUE
  ) + # adding label with percentages and/or counts
  rlang::exec(
    .fn = ggrepel::geom_label_repel,
    mapping = ggplot2::aes(label = label, group = mode),
    position = ggplot2::position_fill(vjust = 0.5), direction = "y",
    show.legend = FALSE,
    na.rm = TRUE
  ) +
  ggplot2::facet_wrap(facets = ~epoch) +
  ggplot2::coord_polar(theta = "y")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have created [ggpie](https://github.com/showteeth/ggpie) to better create pie, donut and rose pie plot, including the optimization of label position, you can have a try.

This is [Vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggpie/vignettes/ggpie.html).

Comment: would you care showing an example of how your package works in that example?